# If f and g are maps such that $g \circ f$ and f are continuous, also $f$ is surjective. Then show that $g$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, algebraic-topology

This question came into my mind while I was seeing the proof of Jordan separation theorem and came across through the following,

Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow U$ be a loop in $U$ with $f(0)=f(1)=x_{0} ,$ where U is a topological space. Let $p:[0,1] \rightarrow S^{1}$ be the map given by
$$
p(x)=(\cos (2 \pi x), \sin (2 \pi x))
$$
Note that $p$ is continuous and is a bijection except at $0$ and $1$.

$p$ induces a map $h: S^{1} \rightarrow U$ such that
$$
h(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
f(0) & \text { if } x=(1,0) \\
f\left(p^{-1}(x)\right) & \text { if } x \neq(1,0)
\end{array}\right.
$$

Here $f=h \circ p$. How h is continuous?

Comment: If someone explains how h is continuous here, it will be a great help.

Comment: If $(x_n,y_n) \to (1,0)$ then  the only limit points of $p^{-1}(x_n,y_n)$ are $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 0):

For $C \subset U$ we have $h^{-1}(C) = p(f^{-1}(C))$. If $C$ is closed in $U$, then $f^{-1}(C)$is closed in $[0,1]$, thus compact. Hence its image under $p$ is compact, hence closed.

Answer (score 0):

The claim of the title is not true. Consider $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \lbrace 0 \rbrace $ defined by $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and $g : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x)=1$ if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $g(x)=0$ otherwise. Then $f$ is continuous and surjective, $g \circ f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the constant (so continuous) map equal to $1$, but $g$ is not at all continuous.